# Question about the Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: approximation

By the Weierstrass approximation theorem for $f\in C[a,b]$ there exists a sequence ($Q_n$) of polynomials such that $Q_n(x) \rightrightarrows f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ or equivalently for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $|Q(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Let $P_n$ be athe space of all polynomials (one real variable) of degree $\leq n$, and 
$E_n(f)=dist(f,P_n)$.

How to show using the Weierstrass theorem that for continuous $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ :
$$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E_n(f)=0.$$

The Weierstrass  theorem says nothing about degrees of approximating $f$ polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious that $\bigl(E_{n}(f)\bigr)$ is non-increasing in $n$, and Weierstrass approximation says $E_{n}(f)$ can be made arbitrarily small by taking $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Weierstrass approximation says that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $\|f - Q\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$. If $N = \deg(Q)$, then $E_{N}(f) < \varepsilon$. Consequently, $E_{n}(f) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. (Added in edit: Since the question this comment addresses was removed, I'm guessing the issue is resolved? :)

Comment: Many thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)